# How to query and display values from a data frame column based on values in a separate vector

Tags: r

I am attempting to query values in one column of a data frame and would like to return a series rows in this data frame based on similar values of a separate vector that I specify in the query. This is basically a subset, but based on values not necessarily included in the data frame.

In my data frame shown here:

```
temperature <- c(30:40)
gas_price <- c(1:11)
date <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14','2015-01-12',
'2012-04-15','2013-09-17','2009-06-26','2011-10-12','2001-07-04','2012-12-25','2015-02-08'))

gas.data <- data.frame(temperature, gas_price, date)
```

I have been attempting to query the temperature column based on a weather forecast vector that we'll call x

```
x  <- c(32,39,37,31,36)
```

Given that x is a 5 day forecast, I've been attempting to query `gas.data$temperature` based on certain values of x. I would like to have rows of the `gas.data` data frame returned with the same `gas.data$temperature` number as the x query.

```
x[x[1] %in% gas.data$temperature]
```

doesn't work nor do my attempts with `which` or `grepRaw`

I am also looking to potentially return a range of values in `gas.data$temperature` based on a specific value query from x, but not sure how to go about that either. I'm assuming it would be similar to the solution above, but could include the `range` function.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: x[x %in% gas.data$temperature]  ... is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Almost, The code `gas.data[gas.data$temperature %in% x,]` is more of what I'm looking for, but I'm also looking to query a specific value in x which works with the code `gas.data[gas.data$temperature %in% x[1],]`. Also, I'm interested in having the query return the a range of similar values to x[1] for example. Any ideas? `gas.data[gas.data$temperature %in% range(x[1]),]` doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without sample output, I am not sure exactly what you are looking for but the following code snippet gives you back the rows in gas.data that corresponds to the temperature in x:

```
gas.data[gas.data$temperature %in% x,]
```

Comment: Yes, this is it, thanks. That code you provided query's through the whole vector of x. I also attempted  `gas.data[gas.data$temperature %in% x[1],]` which just queries a specific value in x. Also works great. I am curious though to find out how to query a range around say x[1]? This code didn't seem to work `gas.data[gas.data$temperature %in% range(x[1]),]`

Comment: Think about what range() is.  range() returns the min and max values of a range.  x[1], in this case is 32, so the range of 32 is min=32 and max=32. The code snippet, using the range(), works fine but it only gives results for 32.  If you want, you can use `gas.data[gas.data$temperature %in% c(32:35),]` or `gas.data[gas.data$temperature %in% x[1:4],]`

Comment: Yes, very true. I did some more digging and that makes sense. I wasn't thinking about R being a statistical program and it having the true definition of range. I appreciate the help, thank you.